# Problem with com.google.gson after upgrading gradle?

Tags: java, android, json, gradle, gson

After upgrading `Gradle` to `8.2.1`, Kotlin `1.9.21` and Java 17 I have an error like:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to cj.a
```

This is my `BaseModel`:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson

abstract class BaseModel {

    inline fun <reified T: BaseModel> parseToJsonString(): String? {
        return try {
            parseToString<T>()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            null
        }
    }

    inline fun <reified T: BaseModel> parseToString(): String {
        return Gson().toJson(this as T)
    }

    companion object {

        inline fun <reified T: BaseModel> fromJsonString(json: String): T? {
            return try {
                decodeFromString(json)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                null
            }
        }

        inline fun <reified T: BaseModel> decodeFromString(json: String): T {
            return Gson().fromJson(json, T::class.java)
        }

    }
}
```

I also receive that exception

```
Exception while processing periodic Task TaskWrapper{task=class y6.g, processed=false}
                                                                                                    java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: y6.g.<init> [class android.content.Context, class u6.a]
```

Why?
I have read some solutions to add in pro guard

```
##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
#-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

-keep class com.google.** { *; }

-keep class sun.misc.** { *; }
# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }

-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer

-keep class * implements com.google.gson.*

##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
```

but it doesn't work. Thanks for any help and suggesstions.

Comment: Can you try to false the minifyEnabled. is it working?

Comment: yes it works on dev environment where minifyEnabled is false

Comment: Is your model class you put @Keep?

Comment: Yes where I extend it I put @Keep, but why it stop working after updating to gradle 8+

Comment: By "Gradle 8.2.1", do you mean the [build tool Gradle](https://gradle.org/releases/) or the [Android Gradle plugin](https://developer.android.com/build/releases/gradle-plugin)? Starting with Android Gradle Plugin 8.0 [R8 full mode is enabled by default](https://developer.android.com/build/releases/past-releases/agp-8-0-0-release-notes#default-changes), which performs more aggressive optimizations.

Comment: Try to copy the content of https://github.com/google/gson/blob/main/gson/src/main/resources/META-INF/proguard/gson.pro to your ProGuard config and let us know if that solves your issue. (I will probably post it as proper answer then)